# Mongodb multiple criteria , return wrong result

Tags: mongodb, coffeescript

I use mongodb in node.js with the mongo-native package and im trying to exclude a document which contains the value 1 in a field called "archive", and I keep getting results that are not appropriate.

Here is my code in coffeescript

```
collection.findOne { _id : new mongo.BSONPure.ObjectID req.params.id ,  "archive" : 0 } ,   (erreur, resultat) ->
       if erreur
          console.log "Erreur: aucun contact de ce nom." + erreur
       else
          res.send resultat
          res.end()
```

and it keeps returning me this :

```
{
  "_id": "51ddb907ae3267d6154a3e64",
  "archive": 1,
  "nom": "G",
  "prenom": "Maxim"
}
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: Is the _id the one you are expecting?

Comment: @CasualT Yeah..absolutely the same id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some parentheses to make sure that the `archive: 0` argument is given to the right function. What you have right now is equivalent to this:

```
collection.findOne({ _id : new mongo.BSONPure.ObjectID(req.params.id,  "archive" : 0) } ,   (erreur, resultat) -> ...
```

so the `archive: 0` argument is sent to `new mongo.BSONPure.ObjectId` and the `findOne` just sees the `_id` argument.

I think you want to say:

```
collection.findOne { _id : new mongo.BSONPure.ObjectID(req.params.id),  "archive" : 0 } ,   (erreur, resultat) -> ...
```

Or use an extra variable to make things less confusing:

```
id = new mongo.BSONPure.ObjectID req.params.id
collection.findOne { _id : id, archive: 0 }, (erreur, resultat) -> ...
```

I tend to put parentheses on all my CoffeeScript function calls to make it visually obvious what's going on; OTOH, I'm a bit of a natural born heretic :)

Comment: lol, the 1st thing I thought when reading the original question was "Gee, I wonder how often no-brackets in coffee script leads to errors".

Comment: @CasualT: Probably even more than they do in Ruby, that's why I don't treat them as optional in either language :)